# python code not running on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror, gensim

I have an already running python code of the [document similarity server](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/simserver.html)

The code runs fine from the commandline, however when I try to run from Jupyter notebook I get the following error (You can find the code below)

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 simServer.queryIndex('National Intergroup Inc said it plans to file a registration statement')

```
<ipython-input-2-81df834abc60> in queryIndex(self, queryText)
     58         print "Querying the INDEX"
     59         doc = {'tokens': utils.simple_preprocess(queryText)}
---> 60         print(self.service.find_similar(doc, min_score=0.4, max_results=50))
```

At first I got a different error message where the solution was to install simserver library within jupyter notebook using the command `!pip install --upgrade simserver` .. but now I do not think there is a missing library that needs to be downloaded

Relevant code from jupyter notebook:

Line where the issue occurs

```
simServer.queryIndex('National Intergroup Inc said it plans to file a registration statement')

#!/usr/bin/env python
import pickle
import os
import re
import glob
import pprint
import json

from gensim import utils
from simserver import SessionServer

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class SimilarityServer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Openning sesesion and setting it to true"
        self.service = SessionServer('tmp/my_server/')
        self.service.open_session()
        self.service.set_autosession(True)

    def indexDocs(self):
        print "Docs indexing and training"
        #train and index
        print "Training"
        self.service.session.train(None,method='lsi',clear_buffer=False)
        print "Indexing"
        self.service.session.index(None)

    def queryIndex(self,queryText):
        print "Querying the INDEX"
        doc = {'tokens': utils.simple_preprocess(queryText)}
        print(self.service.find_similar(doc, min_score=0.4, max_results=50))

simServer = SimilarityServer()
simServer.queryIndex('National Intergroup Inc said it plans to file a registration statement')
```

Comment: It would appear that for what ever reason Jupyter is failing to connect to `tmp/my_server/`. Does that location need to actually be `/tmp/my_server/` as per the documentation here: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/simserver.html?

Comment: @Kyrubas the location can anywhere you like .. but I do not that is the problem here .. the server was able to connect and write the index to the mentioned location .. so I guess the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Could you show the _complete_ traceback so we can see which attribute is actually missing on which object‽